# display long lists in member of member of... on one line in python

Tags: python, list, inspect

I have an object with a huge list somewhere down in the bowels.  The object's dump (e.g. using `print(o)`) doesn't fit on one screen.

But if I could manage to have members that are 1-D lists printed comma-separated on one line, the object would be easier to inspect.

How can this be achieved?

---

EDIT:

Found out that the object I was trying to display had a `__repr__` that explicitly showed it's array content in a vertical manner...  So this question may be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the object I was trying to display had a **repr** that explicitly showed it's array content in a vertical manner... So this question may be closed.

On regular python lists, arrays *are* printed on one line.

[A snippet to show this.](http://codepad.org/R3BvN8vb)

Answer (score 0):

Most of time this gives a readable output:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(o)
```

Comment: And how does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `", ".join(my_long_list)`.

Comment: I would love to do that, but the list is buried deep within a data structure, and I would like to have a solution that introspects the object without me having to knowing it's structure.